# Macro magic for dynamically creating functions with scope

Tags: erlang, elixir, sax

I am using the `xmerl_sax_parser` and the XML structure that I work with is deeply nested so I ended up having a lot of callback functions that just work with the scope stack, which looks like this:

```
defmodule Parser do
  defstruct acc: [], scope: []

  def parse(xml_string) do
    event_state = %Parser{}
    event_fun = &callback/3

    {:ok, state, _} = :xmerl_sax_parser.stream(xml_string, event_fun: event_fun, event_state: event_state)

    state
  end

  defp callback({:startElement, _, 'car', _, _}, _, state) do
    Map.update!(state, :scope, &([:car | &1]))
  end

  defp callback({:endElement, _, 'car', _}, _, %{scope: [:car]} = state) do
    %{state | scope: []}
  end

  defp callback({:startElement, _, 'detail', _, _}, _, %{scope: [:car] = scope} = state) do
    %{state | scope: [:detail | scope]}
  end

  defp callback({:endElement, _, 'detail', _}, _, %{scope: [:detail | [:car] = scope_tail]} = state) do
    %{state | scope: scope_tail}
  end

  defp callback({:startElement, _, 'engine', _, _}, _, %{scope: [:detail, :car] = scope} = state) do
    %{state | scope: [:engine | scope]}
  end

  defp callback({:endElement, _, 'engine', _}, _, %{scope: [:engine | [:detail, :car] = scope_tail]} = state) do
    %{state | scope: scope_tail}
  end

  defp callback({:characters, engine}, _, %{scope: [:engine, :detail, :car], acc: acc} = state) do
    %{state | acc: [engine | acc]}
  end
end
```

So in order to get values that are scoped under `car -> detail -> engine` I had to write 7 functions and it repeats over and over again for every value that I need to get. So the obvious decision is to come up with some macro magic to avoid all that, it could look like this:

```
scope [:car, :detail] do
  text :engine, fn(state, value) -> #some logic end
end
```

but when `text` is called, I can't find a way to access the scope in which it is defined so I am not sure how to go about it.

So the question is, what is the way to implement this kind of DSL that works with scopes? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the long code? That would help us understand the exact code you want to generate better and also let us easily test our solutions.

Comment: @Dogbert Of course, one minute

Comment: @Dogbert I have rewritten the question with a proper example, that should clarify things. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just push a tag name (whatever it is) onto your scope stack (which is now a tag-path stack) on any :startElement, pop on any :endElement, and match against it's tail in :characters clause? That gives you just 3 callback clauses for the example, and an extra one for other required matches.

Comment: @NicoleA. I think that it is actually brilliant, I haven't thought about it, silly of me,  I will try to do it. Thank you very much.